# What is this mongo index with field._ref.$id_1

Tags: index, mongodb

I have a document in a Mongo collection which has an index as follows:

`field._ref.$id_1`

This is tripping up a new database driver we're planning on using - it doesn't seem to understand this format, and I haven't seen it anywhere else before. There's a chance it could have been automatically created.

Looking at index usage, this index is heavily used. There is also an index on just `field_1` which is not used.

`field` is a reference field, storing references to other documents in other collections.

What is this index and why does it have an odd formatting? If I remove it, would the other index `field_1` bear the load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have documents using the older [DBRef convention](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/), which uses a subdocument with `$`-prefixed fields (`$ref`, `$id`, and `$db`) to describe a reference to a document in another collection.

> Looking at index usage, this index is heavily used. There is also an index on just field_1 which is not used.

The index on `field_1` could be used to match the entire subdocument (including all fields in a consistent order), but the common use case appears to be looking up the `_id` reference via `field._ref.$id_1`.

DBRefs have limited support in modern MongoDB driver and server versions and you would definitely be better converting these to [manual references](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/database-references/#manual-references) with more typical field names.

For example, using `field_id` to store a manual reference to the `_id` of a `field` collection.